# Postgres database very slow when running queries

Tags: postgresql

I have a managed database with DigitalOcean that I recently migrated to from a separately hosted database. It's a Postgres 14 database. I felt like I noticed some slowdown after I had migrated but I didn't have an easy way to compare so I just assumed I was wrong. I have however since noticed that it's quite slow.

I have a table "entries" with 4,7m rows. If I run a `select count(*) from entries` query that finishes in 19 seconds. The total database size is around 1.1GB.

I backed up my whole database and imported it into a local database and locally it finishes in 896ms.

Any tips on how I debug this? I originally noticed its slowness with a more complex query than this example. But figured that this route is so simple that I might as well use the count one for example reasons.

I tried running ANALYZE on the entries table, but that didn't really make a difference.

**EDIT:**

This is me running `explain` with the query:

**Locally:**

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=65547.91..65547.92 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Gather  (cost=65547.70..65547.91 rows=2 width=8)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=64547.70..64547.71 rows=1 width=8)
              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using index_entries_on_discarded_at on entries  (cost=0.43..59600.43 rows=1978909 width=0)
```

**DigitalOcean:**

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=340527.64..340527.65 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Gather  (cost=340527.43..340527.64 rows=2 width=8)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=339527.43..339527.44 rows=1 width=8)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on entries  (cost=0.00..334579.74 rows=1979074 width=0)
JIT:
  Functions: 5
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

**Output from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) on Digital Ocean DB:**

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=340527.64..340527.65 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=21958.167..22251.122 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: count(*)
  Buffers: shared hit=19544 read=295245
  ->  Gather  (cost=340527.43..340527.64 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=21925.670..22239.158 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=19544 read=295245
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=339527.43..339527.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=21667.850..21667.880 rows=1 loops=3)
              Output: PARTIAL count(*)
              Buffers: shared hit=19544 read=295245
              Worker 0:  actual time=21539.121..21539.141 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 3
                  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
                  Timing: Generation 0.375 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.351 ms, Emission 74.197 ms, Total 74.923 ms
                Buffers: shared hit=6507 read=102324
              Worker 1:  actual time=21546.859..21546.874 rows=1 loops=1
                JIT:
                  Functions: 3
                  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
                  Timing: Generation 0.351 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.289 ms, Emission 82.109 ms, Total 82.749 ms
                Buffers: shared hit=6352 read=91199
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.entries  (cost=0.00..334579.74 rows=1979074 width=0) (actual time=153.347..21059.836 rows=1581283 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=19544 read=295245
                    Worker 0:  actual time=40.834..20943.050 rows=1638108 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=6507 read=102324
                    Worker 1:  actual time=44.950..20923.007 rows=1471456 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=6352 read=91199
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '568MB', effective_io_concurrency = '2', random_page_cost = '1', work_mem = '1751kB'"
Query Identifier: 1230802159253045228
Planning Time: 0.641 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 11
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 26.149 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 76.294 ms, Emission 515.557 ms, Total 618.000 ms
Execution Time: 22290.983 ms
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` ? That gives you details that are currently missing. All in plain text, as an update of the current question.

Comment: @FrankHeikens done!

Answer (score 0):

The DigitalOcean machine takes 21 seconds to read 800MB from disk (with three parallel processes). I think that is sufficient to explain the difference.

Comment: Meaning it's a hardware limitation issue basically?

Comment: Right, that's what it looks like.

Comment: @Jesper It's a limit on the resources you get. That limit could be the hardware itself, but also the package you pay for. I'm not familiar with DigitalOcean, but at AWS and Azure you get better performance when you pay for more storage. So even for a 500GB database, you might want to pay for 4TB of storage, just because of the additional IO

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks so much for helping me with this! :)